# With AsciiDoc counters: is it possible to change step size?

Tags: counter, asciidoc, asciidoctor

We can have counter starts with 100 and continue with 101, 102, ...:

```
* {counter:num:100}
* {counter:num:100}
```

We can also use letters:

```
* {counter:alpha:X}
* {counter:alpha:X}
```

But is it possible to change/customize the step/increment size and have e.g. jumps of 7? For instance something that will result with:

```
* 107
* 114
* ...
```

Or jumps of two letters each time:

```
* A
* C
* ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need something like that I use the Jamal preprocessor, that I wrote. https://github.com/verhas/jamal

With that you maintain your xxx.adoc.jam file and convert it to xxx.adoc. The simplest way is to edit the adoc document in IntelliJ with the Asciidoctor plugin and have Jama preprocessor installed. That way you edit the macro enriched file, and you get the processed formatted file on the right side, and at the same time it is also saved to the corresponding adoc.

Jamal has several macro packages. The snippet package has a counter macro that has `start` and `step` parameters. Documented here

https://github.com/verhas/jamal/tree/master/jamal-snippet#counter_define

```
The value of the counter starts with 1 by default and is increased by 1 each time the macro is used. For example,

〔@counter:define id=c〕 〔c〕 〔c〕 〔c〕
will result

1 2 3
```

The drawback is that you have to use Jamal, but I believe that is the best choice when reaching the limits and wanting to step over the capabilities of pure Asciidoc.